# How long will people stay frozen (shout)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was wondering about this question,can only people who have tested it answer please, if you have a possible answer but can't be sure put it as a comment, thanks

Comment: Frozen with a shout/spell/what-have-you?

Comment: All of the above

Comment: Looks like it's already been answered here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/40894/8090

Comment: It is answered in the above link, even though the question there was not asking about timings the person provided them :)

Comment: So in that case don't close it

Comment: By the way, @CHARLO, it would be nice to show your appreciation to others who have taken the time to answer your questions. Just had  a quick look and several of your previous questions have perfectly satisfactory answers.

Comment: I would but whenever I try to vote up it tells me to register I'm not an official member

Answer (score 3):

Ok then:

Going by [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/40894/8090) to a different question as my source because no other website I've checked seems to have duration, it looks like the duration of each level

- Level 1: 10 second freeze, 60 second cooldown
- Level 2: 20 second freeze,  90 second cooldown
- Level 3: 30 second freeze, 120 second cooldown

Remember the freeze is broken instantly whenever you attack someone, so it's not really a paralyze-type shout, but more of a take-out-of-the-equation-for-a-while-type shout. It's useful, for example, to freeze a higher level opponent solid to deal with his minions first.